# navigation menu icon color and text is not getting changed in android

Tags: android, android-menu, android-bottomnavigationview

In my cdoe in manin activity xml I am using "android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView" here I am displaying some menu icon in footer .On selection of each icon I am navigating to different screen .
Now I have to change the background of BottomNavigationView that I can do in activity_main xm , change background color , now I have to change the menu icon colot to white an text color should alos come in white . I chnged in menu navigation xml @drawable/icon_home , I changed color white but its not coming . Infact text below icon is also not coming in white . Please help . sugget me . Thank you

// XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.tecnotree.selfcare.ui.main.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

// menu navigation code

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"
    android:title="@string/title_home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_services"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_services"
    android:title="@string/service" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_cart"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_cart"
    android:title="@string/shop" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_payments"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_credit_card"
    android:title="@string/payments" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_more"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_more"
    android:title="@string/more" />
```

/// Activity java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SelfCareManager.CustomerDetailsRequestCallback {

// this is a leftover from Farrukh's initial design. TBD whether this actually needed
//    @BindView(R.id.message)
//    TextView mTextMessage;

    @Inject
    ManagerFactory managerFactory;
    @Inject
    VolatileOps volatileOps;

    @BindView(R.id.navigation)
    BottomNavigationView navigationView;

    private Spinner spinner;
    private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;

    public  ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_dropdown, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView();

        SelfCareManager selfCareManager = managerFactory.getSelfCareManager();
        selfCareManager.getLoginCustomerDetails(
                volatileOps.getString(VolatileKey.LOGIN_NAME),
                volatileOps.getString(VolatileKey.SERVICE_NUMBER),
                true,
                this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Fetching Data", " Please Wait...", false, false);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DaggerMainActivityComponent.builder()
                .appComponent(App.getInstance().getApplicationWideDeps())
                .build()
                .inject(this);

        navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(getSupportFragmentManager());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationHelper);
        navigationHelper.disableShiftMode(navigationView);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new TeaserFragment()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        navigationHelper.reloadCurrentFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomerDetailsReceived(Customer details) {

        loading.dismiss();

        List<String> serviceNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ServiceDetails serviceDetails: details.getServiceDetails()){
            serviceNumbers.add(serviceDetails.getServiceNumber());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, serviceNumbers);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                volatileOps.setString(VolatileKey.SERVICE_NUMBER, (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                navigationHelper.reloadCurrentFragment();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomerDetailsRequestError(String errorMessage) {
        loading.dismiss();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Customer details request error: " + errorMessage);
    }

    public static class NavigationHelper implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        private FragmentManager manager;

        private Fragment currentFragment;

        private HomeFragment homeFragment;
        private ServiceFragment serviceFragment;
        private ShopFragment shopFragment;
        private MoreFragment moreFragment;
        private PaymentsFragment paymentsFragment;

        @Inject
        ManagerFactory managerFactory;
        @Inject
        VolatileOps volatileOps;

        private HomeScreenContract.Presenter homePresenter;
        private ShopScreenContract.Presenter shopPresenter;
        private PaymentsScreenContract.Presenter paymentsPresenter;
        private ServiceScreenContract.Presenter servicePresenter;
        private MoreScreenContract.Presenter morePresenter;

        NavigationHelper(FragmentManager manager) {
            this.manager = manager;

            DaggerMainActivityComponent.builder()
                    .appComponent(App.getInstance().getApplicationWideDeps())
                    .build()
                    .inject(this);

            this.homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            this.homePresenter = new HomeScreenPresenter(homeFragment, managerFactory, volatileOps);
            homeFragment.setPresenter(homePresenter);
            this.serviceFragment = new ServiceFragment();
            this.servicePresenter = new ServiceScreenPresenter(serviceFragment, managerFactory, volatileOps);
            serviceFragment.setPresenter(servicePresenter);
            this.shopFragment = new ShopFragment();
            this.shopPresenter = new ShopScreenPresenter(shopFragment, managerFactory, volatileOps);
            shopFragment.setPresenter(shopPresenter);
            this.moreFragment = new MoreFragment();
            this.morePresenter = new MoreScreenPresenter(moreFragment, managerFactory, volatileOps);
            moreFragment.setPresenter(morePresenter);
            this.paymentsFragment = new PaymentsFragment();
            this.paymentsPresenter = new PaymentsScreenPresenter(paymentsFragment, managerFactory, volatileOps);
            paymentsFragment.setPresenter(paymentsPresenter);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment).commit();
                    currentFragment = homeFragment;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_services:
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, serviceFragment).commit();
                    currentFragment = serviceFragment;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_cart:
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, shopFragment).commit();
                    currentFragment = shopFragment;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_more:
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, moreFragment).commit();
                    currentFragment = moreFragment;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_payments:
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, paymentsFragment).commit();
                    currentFragment = paymentsFragment;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void reloadCurrentFragment(){
            if(currentFragment != null) {
                manager.beginTransaction().detach(currentFragment).attach(currentFragment).commit();
            }else {
               HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
               HomeScreenPresenter homePresenter = new HomeScreenPresenter(homeFragment, managerFactory, volatileOps);
                homeFragment.setPresenter(homePresenter);
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment).commit();
                currentFragment = homeFragment;
            }
        }

        void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
            BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
            try {
                Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
                shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
                shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
                shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
                for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                    //noinspection RestrictedApi
                    item.setShiftingMode(false);
                    // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                    //noinspection RestrictedApi
                    item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                Log.e("NavigationHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.e("NavigationHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think can help you for both case in case of checked or unchecked icon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon_home" android:tint="@color/white" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon_home" android:tint="@color/grey" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon_home" android:tint="@color/white" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: can you please chek my above menu ... I am using that\

Comment: after going @drawable/icon 
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="24dp">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="M11.99,18.54l-7.37,-5.73L3,14.07l9,7 9,-7 -1.63,-1.27 -7.38,5.74zM12,16l7.36,-5.73L21,9l-9,-7 -9,7 1.63,1.27L12,16z"/>
</vector>
"

Comment: you can create icon drawable and put on navigation item

Comment: or also u can use this in bottom navigation view property
 
app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"

Comment: Thanks for your help , I changed in android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView  then it works

Comment: after changing in menu it was not working .. Thanks :)